Get multiple response as Promise Array when sending message with chrome.tabs.sendMessage
When all_frames: true is set in manifest.json, the content script runs on all frames of the target page, but when a message is sent to the content script from another script, I would like to know how to get the response of all frames as Promise array like [Promise(Response of frame1), Promise(Response of frame2)...].
The extension and test page I created for this question can be found on my Github.

Extension
Testpage

If anyone knows of a better way to do this, I would be grateful if anyone could let me know.
Thanks.

you mean, like Promise.all

Nope,I know this ofc.What I want to know is how to store all responses in a Promise array, not just the first one.

is "a promise array" a Promise that resolves to an array, or an array of Promises?

Self-resolved
chrome.tabs.query({active:true, currentWindow:true}, async tabs => {
    let promises = await sendMessagePromises(tabs[0].id)
    console.log(promises)
})

async function sendMessagePromises(tabId){
    let promises = []
    let frames = await chrome.webNavigation.getAllFrames({tabId:tabId})
    frames.forEach(f => {
        let promise = chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {type:'ping'}, {frameId:f.frameId})
        promises.push(promise)
    })
    return promises
}

screenshot

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
